# How can I get mybb's cache into my own script?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, backend, mybb

How can I get mybb's cache into my own script?
I mean :

```
$mybb->cache->read("test");
$mybb->cache->update("test");
```

i want to do something like this
I found a lot of resources on the internet, but I couldn't find the result I wanted, but I couldn't find how to search.